# Python: Format headers

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting, format

So I have some headers that I need to format automatically. I have always done it manually and It's getting boring now and I'm searching for a way to do it automatically. I have tried using Python built in formatting but that didn't work.

These are the headers:

```
headers = {
    authority: discord.com
    method: POST
    path: /api/v9/auth/register
    scheme: https
    accept: */*
    accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
    content-length: 2840
    content-type: application/json
    origin: https://discord.com
    referer: https://discord.com/register
    sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="96", "Google Chrome";v="96"
    sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
    sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
    sec-fetch-dest: empty
    sec-fetch-mode: cors
    sec-fetch-site: same-origin
    user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36
    x-debug-options: bugReporterEnabled
    x-discord-locale: en-US
}
```

And i'm looking to format them like this:

```
    "authority": "discord.com",
    "method": "POST",
    "path": "/api/v9/auth/register",
```

Comment: What *specifically* does "that didn't work" mean?

Comment: Are you using an IDE? Perhaps PyCharm?

Comment: Yes, I'm using PyCharm

Comment: @ScottHunter It just basically doesn't do anything. Adds some spaces and that's it.

Comment: I'm going to post a fix for you. Just give me a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do special formatting using something called a regular expression. Some IDE's support using these, and PyCharm is one of them.

Here are the steps:

1. Press Ctrl + R and select the star button at the end of the first row
2. Type in first row: `^\s+(.+): (.+)` and in the second row: `'$1': '$2',`
3. Press Replace All and exit out of the replace tool window
4. Press Ctrl + Alt + L to reformat the dictionary

You can remove the comma on the last item in dictionary if desired. I used apostrophes instead of quotation marks because some of the items have quotes.

[image]

Comment: I did every step, but It doesn't let me click replace all, says 0 results

Comment: I forgot to mention that you need to have that blue star selected. Did you do that?

Comment: I just found it yeah, thank you it works